# Center Data Label over XY scatter with lines

Tags: vba, charts, alignment

I am in the process of creating the following chart: 
[image]

But I need each data label to be centered over the line that gets created instead of the end point of the line. I have the following:

```
    Set mypts = mysrs.Points
    mypts(mypts.Count).ApplyDataLabels

        With mypts(mypts.Count).DataLabel
            .ShowSeriesName = True
            .ShowCategoryName = False
            .ShowValue = False
            ' optional parameters
            .Orientation = 0
            .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
```

Does any body know how to center the data labels, which I gave it by giving each series a name?

Comment: For the auto options I think you get Centre OR above. If you are able to do it manually using the labels option menu then record a macro whilst you do so and use that code as your template.

Comment: Can you share a small subset of your data as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering a label above each line will involve creating another data series that calculates the line's center. Without having access to your data, I turned to @JonPeltier 's excellent [post on connecting two XY data series](https://peltiertech.com/connect-two-xy-series-with-arrows/).

*Your question involves your custom VBA code. My example here should be taken as the steps needed to set up the data. At your choice you can either set up your data on the worksheet, or have your VBA code create this "extra" data series to add to the chart (again, because I don't know what your data looks like I can't recommend a solution specific to your problem).*

I won't repeat all the details of creating the chart, but here's an example of the data and the resulting chart:

[image]

[image]

Now, setting up the mid-point data isn't difficult. The mid-point is a quick formula `=((D2-A2)/2)+A2`, copied down the column.

Added to the chart, select the "MidPoint" and "Value" columns and <kbd>cntl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> copy the data, then select the chart and "Paste Special" as a new data series.

[image]

> **A Quick Note:** DO NOT put your mid-point data on the same rows as the A and B data. I did this initially and Excel (in its own private wisdom) associated the data with column A. The results on the chart aren't pretty.

Next to last step is to select the new data series and select "Add Data Labels", then check the box for "Value From Cells". Choose the data range for the labels, e.g. cells `C17:C20`.

[image]

Finally, format the labels to only show the "Value From Cells" (uncheck the "Y" data label) and set the marker to "None". Then you have the centered label for your line.

[image]

Comment: That kinda worked. Trouble is I have the data linked to a dynamic table...So value from cells needs to be in a vba type.

Comment: Why can't your VBA put the values into appropriate cells for the tabular data?